# Stream through files in 7-zip archive

Tags: java, python, compression, 7zip

I'd like to write a Python or Java app to iterate over all of the many small files in a 7-zip (.7z) archive.  Is there a convenient way to do this in a streaming and efficient fashion, i.e. without repeatedly running `7z` to extract individual files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered a 3rd-party library like [pylzma](http://www.joachim-bauch.de/projects/pylzma/)? It includes a [module](https://github.com/fancycode/pylzma/blob/master/py7zlib.py) for reading from and writing to 7-zip archives.